# How do you say live between?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

I want to know how you say live between in German. For example, I want to say 'He lived between 1900 - 1980.' How do I say it?

Can I use zwischen in this case? Can you do this sentence without zwischen?

Also, is this a correct translation for 'He dived his head to water before he composed music':

Wenn er komponierte, habe er seine kopf in kaltes wasser tauchen

Comment: I think zwischen is okay, but "von... bis..." sounds better (not native speaker).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your questions. Please consider asking a new question for your 2nd question (in fact, you can ask as many as you like!) as it is not related to your first question :)

Comment: _"Wenn er komponierte, habe er seine kopf in kaltes wasser tauchen"_ ist kompletter Nonsens, und weit entfernt von einem korrekten deutschen Satz.

Comment: Two questions here, and both could be solved using a dictionary or any translation service.... vtc therefor...

Comment: It is annoying that for 3:2 close only the 3-person-reason is shown. My vote was the 5th, the 2nd to say "needs more focus". In the current form the question is very unclear and confusing, but by splitting plus better describing words it might be saved.

Answer (score 3):

> He lived between 1900 - 1980.

Er lebte von 1900 bis 1980.